# godot radom spawn location

Tags: godot, spawn, gdscript, godot4

So i have been learning godot and now i want to implement random spawn locations in the game, right now i can only spawn on one side and i want 4 at least.

---

```
extends Path3D

var timer = 0
var spawntime = 2
var enemy = preload("res://whitecube.tscn")

func _process(delta):
    timer += delta
    if (timer > spawntime)
        var newenemy = enemy.instantiate()
        add_child(newenemy)
        timer = 0
```

this is the code i have in my path3D to spawn them in each 2 seconds
extends PathFollow3D

---

```
@export var movespeed = 6

func _process(delta):
    set_progress(get_progress() + movespeed * delta)
```

and this is the path they folow and speed

---

i tried to create 1 markers3d and drag the path/pathfollow3d scene inside,then copy and paste it 4 times but the paths are all connected so if i move the path1, the path 2 moves too and i dont know why.Anyways After creating that i thought about creating a node3d which would be used as a spawn location and a random number generator from 1 to 4, inside the "if (timer > spawntime)" i would do one if for each location and set the spawnlocation = marker1 ,2 ,3 or 4 depending on the random number.

i have been learning this language for about 2 months only. So if what i am saying is stupid i deeply apologize and ask you for your help. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, your goal is to make 4 separate path3D nodes for enemies to follow?

Comment: @LukeTrenaman it is exactly what you said. i want four paths ( they are straight lines ) and then i want to pick a random one, then spawn the enemy in the beggining of that path and follow it until its end.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code `path` is a reference to the `Path3D`. Since you are writing in an script attached to the `Path3D`, you do not need `path`. So instead of  - for example - `path.curve.get_baked_length()` you can write `self.curve.get_baked_length()` or simply `curve.get_baked_length()`. However I'll keep writing `path` for generality.

*Furthermore, if you need to pick between multiple `Path3D` you could have references to them in an `Array`, pick one at random from the array (for example with `pick_random`), and that will be your `path`.*

---

### Picking a position at random on the `Path3D`

Now, the task is getting a position at random from a `Path3D`, correct?

I'll start by getting the length of the `Path3D`:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
```

Now we can pick a distance along the `Path3D` like this:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
var offset := randf_range(0.0, path_length)
```

Then we sample the `Path3D` on that distance:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
var offset := randf_range(0.0, path_length)
var result_path_position := path.curve.sample_baked(offset)
```

Assuming we are going to add a new instance as child of a different node, let us convert that to global coordinates:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
var offset := randf_range(0.0, path_length)
var result_global_position := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))
```

---

In the following code `node_parent` is the reference to the `Node3D` under which you will add the new instance as child. Again, if you are writing the code on an script attached to that `Node3D` you do not need to write `node_parent`.

The next task is to instantiate a new child at that position, right?

So let us go from global coordinates to local coordinates of the `node_parent`:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
var offset := randf_range(0.0, path_length)
var result_global_position := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))
var result_position := node_parent.to_local(result_global_position)
```

**Note**: If `node_parent` and `path` are the same node, you don't need these global an local conversions at all. You can work with the `result_path_position` we had above.

New let us instantiate, set position, and add the instance as child:

```
var path_length := path.curve.get_baked_length()
var offset := randf_range(0.0, path_length)
var result_global_position := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))
var result_position := node_parent.to_local(result_global_position)

var instance := scene.instantiate()
instance.position = result_position
node_parent.add_child(instance)
```

---

### Following a `Path3D`

If you want to do this with `PathFollow3D` then each instance needs to be a child of a different `PathFollow3D`. The `PathFollow3D` must be added as children of the `Path3D`. And you can control the position along the path with either `progress` or `progress_ratio`.

For example, if you want the instances to advance along the path at a given speed, you would - of course - start by setting the `progress` to `0.0`, and then each frame you increase `progress` by `speed * delta`.

---

Of course, you don't need `PathFollow3D`. You could have a reference to the `Path3D`

```
@export var path:Path3D
```

You also need the speed you want to advance at, and keep track of your position on the track:

```
@export var path:Path3D
@export var speed:float


var progress:float
```

And advance yourself:

```
@export var path:Path3D
@export var speed:float


var progress:float


func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    progress = progress + speed * delta
    var dest := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(progress))
    global_position = dest
```

---

You could, instead of keeping track of progress, find the closest position to the path:

```
@export var path:Path3D
@export var speed:float


func _ready() -> void:
    if path.curve.point_count == 0:
        global_position = path.global_position
    else:
        global_position = path.to_global(path.curve.get_point_position(0))


func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var offset = path.curve.get_closest_offset(path.to_local(global_position))
    offset = offset + speed * delta
    var dest := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))
    global_position = dest
```

*Here I'm placing the instance at the start of the path in `_ready()`. It is also an example of handling an empty `Path3D` (if the `Path3D` has no points, I place the instance at the position of the `Path3D` itself).*

You can also imagine that you could find out where is the closest offset, and compare it with the current position, so we can write code to return to the path (for example if something can push the instance off track):

```
var offset = path.curve.get_closest_offset(path.to_local(global_position))
var ideal := path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))
var dest := global_position
if ideal.distance_to(global_position) > 0.001:
    # Return to the path
    dest = global_position.move_toward(ideal, speed * delta)
else:
    # Follow the path
    offset = offset + speed * delta
    dest = path.to_global(path.curve.sample_baked(offset))

global_position = dest
```

*This would not have been possible with `PathFollow3D`.*

---

Handling if the instance reached the end of the `Path3D` is possible by taking the length of the `Path3D` (as shown in the case of picking a position at random) and comparing the offset with that. I'll leave that to you.

---

It is also possible to use `sample_baked_with_rotation` which gives you a `Transform3D`, so the instance can follow the rotation of the `Path3D`, the code would need to be adjusted to work with `Transform3D` instead of just `Vector3`. For that you will need to get the position of the `Transform3D` by reading its `origin` property. And, of course, you would set `globa_transform` instead of `global_position`.

However, I would suggest to rotate according to the direction the instance is moving (i.e. the direction between `global_position` and `dest`) which would also work when the instance is returning to the path.

If you don't need to interpolate the rotation, using `look_at` to look at `dest` would suffice, which reminds me, you can query the up vector from the path with `sample_baked_up_vector`.

---

Note that in these codes I'm writing `global_position`. If you are moving a `CharacterBody3D` you might want to use `move_and_slide` instead...

```
velocity = (dest - global_position) / delta
move_and_slide()
```

---

*Again, I hope you can adapt this code to your needs.*

Comment: Firstly i would like to thank you for helping me AGAIN. secondly i think you might have missunderstood and that is 100% my fault so i recommend you read the comment i made above Again im not experienced so if i say something wrong or stupid correct me please. you thought i wanted to pick a random position inside the path but what i want is to pick THE path so i only need the initial point and them instantiate the enemy in it and make him follow it. Again im sorry for the missunderstanding, i should have been more specific from the beggining